# Why key parameters in Python has to be "so complicated"?

Tags: python, sorting, key

This code is from **Bro Code** Python Course

```py
students = (("Squidward", "F", 60),
            ("Sandy", "A", 33),
            ("Patrick", "D", 36),
            ("Spongebob", "B", 20),
            ("Mr. Krabs", "C", 78))

age = lambda ages: ages[2]
sorted_students = sorted(students, key=age)

for i in sorted_students:
    print(i)
```

I wonder why **"key"** has to have "so complicated" syntax

What is ages and ages[2] anyway?
How does python know that I was referring to the index in the tuple?

In short, I completely don't understand the concept of key=age where age is memory address of ages[2]

I tried it solve like

```py
age = 2
sorted_students = sorted(students, key=age)
```

or just

```py
sorted_students = sorted(students, key=2)
```

Comment: [Look into the operator module in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html).  Your code can be simplified using `operator.itemgetter`. `from operator import itemgetter; sorted_students = sorted(students, key=itemgetter(2))`

Comment: If you feel that referring to age by using index (in this case `2`) in the tuple is not beautiful, you can use `typing.NamedTuple`. You could use custom `Student` class for example, and refer to their age using `.age` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key` parameter is a function.  Named lambdas are considered bad style because, as you point out, they’re confusing-looking.  If you’re going to name it, use a `def`, and use names that make it more clear what the function is doing.

Eg replace this:

```
age = lambda ages: ages[2]
sorted_students = sorted(students, key=age)
```

with this:

```
def get_age(student):
    return student[2]

sorted_students = sorted(students, key=get_age)
```

and hopefully the way `key` is working will seem less mysterious.

Answer (score 2):

I feel the naming may be confusing you. This does the same:

```
# just defining the students, although it's odd that it's a tuple of tuples
students = (("Squidward", "F", 60),
            ("Sandy", "A", 33),
            ("Patrick", "D", 36),
            ("Spongebob", "B", 20),
            ("Mr. Krabs", "C", 78))

# sorting 'students' by the 3rd element of each tuple
sorted_students = sorted(students, key=lambda student: student[2])

# print each student from the sorted result
for student in sorted_students:
    print(student)
```

Assigning a lambda a name is generally a bad idea, so that step has been removed here. And the naming `ages` was confusing, after all the `lambda` takes a student and returns their age (which is `student[2]`, the 3rd element of the student tuple).

And looping using `i` makes sense if the variable `i` is used as an index. But since this loop loops over `students` and gets each `student` in turn, naming the loop variable `student` makes more sense.

The only real complication is the `lambda`. Since you want to sort by the 3rd element of each tuple, you need some way to tell the `sorted()` function that. You can pass a function as the `key`, which takes each element of the collection to be sorted and returns a value to sort by. In your case, each element is a tuple, and you want to return the 3rd element of it. Instead of defining a function with `def` and passing the name of the function (as user @samwise suggests, another readable and correct solution), you can also just define a `lambda` right there, which is just an unnamed function.